# dart2js + dart:mirrors - hasReflectedType always returns false?

Tags: dart

I've been trying to get some dart:mirrors code to work in javascript and just discovered that the JS method for ClassMirror.hasReflectedType looks like this:

```js
get$hasReflectedType: function() {
  return false;
  "269";
},
```

I guess it'll always return false then?  Is this not supported in dart2js yet?

Comment: no since 1.0 was released much of the api and dart2js was stable and complete with the exception of reflection, the reflection library is still open to change and reflection is not supported in dart2js, I'd link to a reference here but I cant for the life of me remember where I read that, some where on news.dartlang.org

Comment: The [Reflection in Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/reflection-with-mirrors/) page mentions the mirrors API is evolving, even past 1.0.

Comment: Yeah, I see that.  No big deal for now, can't wait for it to fully work through dart2js though.

Comment: 2020 and still no reflection for web apps or Flutter?